# Sort an array based on another array in javascript while keeping not sorted elements at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that i want to sort based on another array. If both array is the same length, the code below works fine. However, if my array called `order` is missing an element, i still want to display that at the end of the new sorted array. Here is a quick example:

```js
//Source arrays
var order = [{_id: '123', type: '2'},{_id: '123', type: '1'}];
var elements = [{_id: '124', type: '1', name: '(should be last, not sorted)'},{_id: '123', type: '1', name: 'second(should be second)'},{_id: '123', type: '2', name: 'third(should be first)'}];

var sorted = [];
for (var i = 0, len = order.length; i < len; i++) {
    var element = elements.filter(function (el) {
  return el.type == order[i]['type'] &&
               el._id == order[i]['_id'];
    });
    sorted.push(element[0]);
}

//Just for testing
var list = document.createElement('ul');
for (var i = 0, len = sorted.length; i < len; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorted[i]['name']));
      list.appendChild(item);
}
document.getElementById('list').appendChild(list);
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

As you can see, now i only have two items in my sorted array. How can i add the missing item(s) from `elements` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.findIndex` to get index and then sort accordingly

```js
var order = [{_id: '123', type: '2'},{_id: '123', type: '1'}];
var elements = [{_id: '124', type: '1', name: '(should be last, not sorted)'},{_id: '123', type: '1', name: 'second(should be second)'},{_id: '123', type: '2', name: 'third(should be first)'}];


elements.sort(function(a, b) {
  var MAX_VALUE = 9999999;
  var index_a = order.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el._id === a._id && el.type === a.type;
  });
  var index_b = order.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el._id === b._id && el.type === b.type;
  });
  
  index_a = index_a < 0? MAX_VALUE : index_a;
  index_b = index_b < 0? MAX_VALUE : index_b;

  return index_a > index_b ? 1 : index_a < index_b ? -1 : 0
});

console.log(elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and an object for the sort order. If no order is given, then the element is moved to the end.

```js
function sortWithOrder(array) {
    function getOrder(o) { return (orderObj[o._id] || {})[o.type] || Infinity; }

    var orderObj = Object.create(null);
    array.forEach(function (a, i) {
        orderObj[a._id] = orderObj[a._id] || {};
        orderObj[a._id][a.type] = i + 1;
    });
    return function (a, b) {
        return getOrder(a) - getOrder(b);
    };
}

var order = [{ _id: '123', type: '2' }, { _id: '123', type: '1' }],
    elements = [{ _id: '124', type: '1', name: '(should be last, not sorted)' }, { _id: '123', type: '1', name: 'second(should be second)' }, { _id: '123', type: '2', name: 'third(should be first)' }];

elements.sort(sortWithOrder(order));
console.log(elements);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Any specific reason to define `getOrder` a local function inside `Sort`?

Comment: @Rajesh, because it is only locally used.

Comment: But will that not *define/override* same function for every iteration. Also does this have any performance benefit? Sorry for so many queries.

Comment: @Rajesh, i changed the style. but the original function does not change for every call. it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sorted = elements.sort((a, b) => 
               (order.findIndex(i => a._id === i._id && a.type === i.type) + 1 || order.length + 1) 
             - (order.findIndex(i => b._id === i._id && b.type === i.type) + 1 || order.length + 1)
             );
```

```js
'use strict';

var order = [{
  _id: '123',
  type: '2'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '1'
}];
var elements = [{
  _id: '124',
  type: '1',
  name: '(should be last, not sorted)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '2',
  name: 'third(should be first)'
}, {
  _id: '124',
  type: '1',
  name: '(should be last, not sorted)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '1',
  name: 'second(should be second)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '1',
  name: 'second(should be second)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '2',
  name: 'third(should be first)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '2',
  name: 'third(should be first)'
}, {
  _id: '123',
  type: '1',
  name: 'second(should be second)'
}, {
  _id: '124',
  type: '1',
  name: '(should be last, not sorted)'
}];

var sorted = elements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (order.findIndex(function (i) {
    return a._id === i._id && a.type === i.type;
  }) + 1 || order.length + 1) - (order.findIndex(function (i) {
    return b._id === i._id && b.type === i.type;
  }) + 1 || order.length + 1);
});

//Just for testing
var list = document.createElement('ul');
for (var i = 0, len = sorted.length; i < len; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorted[i]['name']));
      list.appendChild(item);
}
document.getElementById('list').appendChild(list);
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```